# How to know if materialize css modal is open or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I am using materialize css modal. I want to change style of my div whenever modal is opened.

I have tried the below code but it does not seem to work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.modal').modal();
    if($('.modal').isOpen == true) {
        document.getElementById("a").style.zIndex = "1000";
    }
});
```

I am looking for a boolean value to check whether modal is open or not.

Comment: try $('.modal').modal("isOpen") instead

Comment: @RV $('.modal').modal("isOpen") does not seem to work.

Comment: you are trying to run something when it opens. right?

Comment: Yes, I want to change css of my div when modal is opened

Comment: in that case use this selector ".modal.open" then target your div and apply required css. open class will be added only when popup is open

Comment: @SumitPatel I didn't get you. Can you please provide an example?

Comment: like this .model.open .classname {color:#000}

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`M.Modal.getInstance(elem)`](https://materializecss.com/modals.html#methods) and [`isOpen`](https://materializecss.com/modals.html#properties) property

```js
$('.modal').modal()

var instance = M.Modal.getInstance(document.getElementById('modal1'))
instance.open()

console.log(instance.isOpen)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<!-- Modal Trigger -->
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a>

<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="modal1" class="modal modal-fixed-footer">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h4>Modal Header</h4>
    <p>A bunch of text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Materialize modal append class open to opened modal, you can check if your modal id has class open

```
// jQuery
$('#modal1').hasClass('open')

// or VanillaJs
document.querySelector('#myModalId').classList.contains('open')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `onOpenStart`  Function - Callback function called before modal is opened.

Or You can call `onOpenEnd` Function - Callback function called after modal is opened.

For more detail you can read.

[materializecss](https://materializecss.com/modals.html)